# Proof about rank of a matrix depending on the value of its determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, matrix-rank

I've got the following exercise:
$A \in M(2 \times 2; \mathbb{R})$. Show that 
$$\text{rank}(A)= \begin{cases} 2, \ \ \   \ \ \ \text{if det(A) ≠ 0} \\ \leq 1, \  \ \text{if det(A) = 0} \end{cases}$$

I am not sure how to start this. I am grateful for every hint.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

only just an **HINT**

rank(A) = #numer of linearly independent columns

thus

1. rank(A)=2 $\iff det(A) ≠ 0$
2. rank(A)<2 $\iff det(A) = 0$

NOTE take a look at a good book on linear algebra